# Appending new columns to a datatable based on matching categories

Tags: r

I have a table as follows

```
Ab1        Ab2         Ab3
Meronem    Eus         Biclar
Aug        Tazocin  
Aug        Pc
Aug        Eth         Amukin
Aug     
Tazocin     
Kefzol     Avelox      Meronem
Aug        Amukin      Tazocin
Kefzol     Tazocin
```

I would like to categorize the datatable based on Ab corresponding to the Ab class

```
Ab           Ab class
Aug          bl
Pentrexyl    Pcl
Zitromax     Mld
Azactam      Mb
Kefzol       Cp
Biclar       Mld
Eth          Mld
Pc           Pcl
Meronem      Cb
Tazocin      bl
Amukin       Am
Eus          Ts
```

I would like to have my final table in this manner.

```
Ab1      Ab2      Ab3      bl    Pcl    Mld    Mb    Cp    Cb    Am    Ts  
Meronem  Eus      Biclar   0     0      1      0     0     1     0     1
Aug      Tazocin           2     0      0      0     0     0     0     0
Aug      Pc                1     1      0      0     0     0     0     0
Aug      Eth      Amukin   1     0      1      0     0     0     1     0
```

I tried assigning values to keys and matching them. But I am unable to find a fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But shouldn't Meronem have a 1 under 'Cb' under your example?

Comment: @Heroka:Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses some data-reshaping to get the second part (AB-classes) in the right format, and then simply cbinds it to the first part.

```
library(reshape2)
#ad a line ID
ab$line_ID <- 1:nrow(ab)

#turn to long format
ab_long <- melt(ab, id.var="line_ID", value.name="Ab")

#merge with ab-classdata (removing NA's for convenience)
ab_long_merge <- merge(ab_long[!is.na(ab_long$Ab),], ab_classes, by="Ab", all.x=T) 

#create our table (as a dataframe in right format using dcast)
ab_wide_merge <- dcast(line_ID~Abclass, data=ab_long_merge, fun.agg=length, value.var="Abclass")[,-1] #-1 to remove line

#create our desired output
output <- cbind(ab[,1:3], ab_wide_merge)

> output
      Ab1     Ab2     Ab3 Am bl Cb Cp Mld Pcl Ts NA
1 Meronem     Eus  Biclar  0  0  1  0   1   0  1  0
2     Aug Tazocin    <NA>  0  2  0  0   0   0  0  0
3     Aug      Pc    <NA>  0  1  0  0   0   1  0  0
4     Aug     Eth  Amukin  1  1  0  0   1   0  0  0
5     Aug    <NA>    <NA>  0  1  0  0   0   0  0  0
6 Tazocin    <NA>    <NA>  0  1  0  0   0   0  0  0
7  Kefzol  Avelox Meronem  0  0  1  1   0   0  0  1
8     Aug  Amukin Tazocin  1  2  0  0   0   0  0  0
9  Kefzol Tazocin    <NA>  0  1  0  1   0   0  0  0
```

data used:

```
ab <- structure(list(Ab1 = c("Meronem", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", 
"Tazocin", "Kefzol", "Aug", "Kefzol"), Ab2 = c("Eus", "Tazocin", 
"Pc", "Eth", NA, NA, "Avelox", "Amukin", "Tazocin"), Ab3 = c("Biclar", 
NA, NA, "Amukin", NA, NA, "Meronem", "Tazocin", NA)), .Names = c("Ab1", 
"Ab2", "Ab3"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

ab_classes <- structure(list(Ab = structure(c(2L, 10L, 12L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 
9L, 8L, 11L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("Amukin", "Aug", "Azactam", 
"Biclar", "Eth", "Eus", "Kefzol", "Meronem", "Pc", "Pentrexyl", 
"Tazocin", "Zitromax"), class = "factor"), Abclass = structure(c(2L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 8L), .Label = c("Am", 
"bl", "Cb", "Cp", "Mb", "Mld", "Pcl", "Ts"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Ab", 
"Abclass"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
#read in using read.table
```

Comment: Thats a ton. Thats exactly how I wanted my data to look. But could you explain in line 4 (ab_long_merge), what is ab_classes? I am unable to figure that out.

Comment: Oops, that was the name I gave to your 'classes' table. Will edit with 'data used'.

Comment: Okie. Its clear now. I appreciate your help. Many thanks.